# How to enable SSL for SmtpClient in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, smtpclient

Is there a way to set the EnableSSL from the web.config?

I could set this property in code, but that wouldn't work for the Simple Mail Web Event and other classes that uses the default Smtp Server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For .NET 3 and earlier: You can't. You have to manage it by hand.

For more information you can see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikas/2008/04/29/bug-asp-net-2-0-passwordrecovery-web-control-cannot-send-emails-to-ssl-enabled-smtp-servers/.

For .NET 4: You can.

See http://theoldsewingfactory.com/2011/01/06/enable-ssl-in-web-config-for-smtpclient/

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod=”network”>
                <network host="localhost"
                         port="25"
                         enableSsl="true"
                         defaultCredentials="true" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As of .net 4.0 you can now set enableSsl in the webconfig: http://theoldsewingfactory.com/2011/01/06/enable-ssl-in-web-config-for-smtpclient/

Comment: @eKek0, as the accepted answer, could you update the text to say that you can in .net 4, please?  See the ilivewithian's comment for the reference.

Answer (score 20):

I have a dirty workaround (until .NET 4.0 comes out). Instead of changin my code it relies on the used port to determine if SSL is required or not.

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
client.EnableSsl = client.Port == 587 || client.Port == 465;
// This could also work
//client.EnableSsl = client.Port != 25;
```

I said it was a dirty hack, but it working fine for the different configurations that we encounter.

Answer (score 5):

this works for me in .net 4

E.G. in web.config

```
network host="somesmtpserver" userName="do_not_reply@yourserver.com" 
password="whatever" port="25" enableSsl="true"
```

Comment: enableSsl="true" isn't actually supported

Answer (score 3):

Giles Roberts Jan 18 '12 at 18:01 said

this works for me in .net 4

E.G. in web.config

```
network host="somesmtpserver" userName="do_not_reply@yourserver.com" 
password="whatever" port="25" enableSsl="true"
```

Port 25 is not a SSL port. Port 25 is the default SMTP port. Furthermore the web.config code is partly filled out. The code should be

```
    <system.net>
         <mailSettings>
              <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="user@gmail.com">
                     <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
                     userName="user@gmail.com"
                     password="********"
                     port="587"
                     defaultCredentials="true"
                     enableSsl="true" />
             </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

This settings above is more accurate then the original web.config code. I don't know witch method is better. Using web.config or using the code-behind page to send the e-mail. No matter witch method you use the code-behind file has to be modified. I say this because you have to wire up From, Subject, and Body text boxes. I'm taking it for granted that the end results that you want to send a message through an aspx web page

Comment: This is the same code that I use in my web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, there is a way to do it for the 'forgot password' built in .net login controls though.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/vikas/archive/2008/04/29/bug-asp-net-2-0-passwordrecovery-web-control-cannot-send-emails-to-ssl-enabled-smtp-servers.aspx

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use in my web.config file.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have searched almost everywhere for this.

But it seems there is no way we can configure EnableSsl Property in web.config.

Have a look at [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=281277)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in the `MailSettingsSectionGroup`. See below code:

```
Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
var mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

_smtpClient.Host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
_smtpClient.Port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
_smtpClient.EnableSsl = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.**EnableSsl**;
_smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName, mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password);
_smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

It seems that `EnableSsl` does not exist as a property under Network because when I run and debug this, I can see the value, but can't compile the code due to missing ExtensionMethod.

Answer (score 0):

I appears the class is sealed, so i made a manual extension. I thought i'd provide it for others here. Hope it can be of use to others.

```
/// <summary>
/// OldSchool extension of SmtpNetWorkElement, since it's sealed.
/// </summary>
public class SmtpNetworkElementEx
{
    private readonly SmtpNetworkElement m_SmtpNetWorkElement;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SmtpNetworkElementEx"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SmtpNetworkElementEx()
    {
        Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
        var mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

        if (mailSettings == null)
            return;

        m_SmtpNetWorkElement = mailSettings.Smtp.Network;
    }

    public string Host { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.Host; } }
    public bool DefaultCredentials { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.DefaultCredentials; } }
    public string ClientDomain { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.ClientDomain; } }
    public string TargetName { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.TargetName; } }
    public int Port { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.Port; } }
    public string UserName { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.UserName; } }
    public string Password { get { return m_SmtpNetWorkElement.Password; } }
    public bool EnableSsl { get { return Convert.ToBoolean(m_SmtpNetWorkElement.ElementInformation.Properties["enableSsl"].Value); } }
}
```

Use this way:

```
var smtpSettings = new SmtpNetworkElementEx();

_smtpClient.Host = smtpSettings.Host;
_smtpClient.Port = smtpSettings.Port;
_smtpClient.EnableSsl = smtpSettings.EnableSsl;
_smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpSettings.UserName, smtpSettings.Password);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just extend the class and set EnableSsl = true and use that class.

Comment: The SmtpClient class is sealed