# Send email via asp.net throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I wrote this code in asp.net for sending email:

```
MailMessage mailObject = new MailMessage("a@b.com(I use fake email, exactly this email)", "info@mydomain.com", "contact us", "Test message");
SmtpClient smtpC = new SmtpClient("my smtp server name");
smtpC.Send(mailObject);
```

But I receive this exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Also I can not connect to my "smpt server name" via tel net:

> telnet SMTPServerName 25
>   Connecting To SMTPServerName...Could not open connection to the host, on port
>   25: Connect failed

Is there any standard for troubleshooting this?

Comment: Did you try to send a test smtp message from the "manage" option near IIS ?

Comment: Have you tested the smtp server hostname with telnet? http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html

Comment: Have you overwriten smtp settings in your web.config? like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767450/how-does-my-asp-net-app-get-the-smtp-settings-automatically-from-web-config

Comment: @JPHellemons no, I didnt write anything in my web.config

Comment: telnet SMTPServerName 25
Connecting To SMTPServerName...Could not open connection to the host, on port
25: Connect failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the server name or port is incorrect. Make sure you can send from an SMTP client before troubleshooting further in your code.

Comment: agree, check your smtp server first.

Comment: I really dont know how to do that

Comment: @masoudkeshavarz - if you don't know how to configure an email client, you can ask at http://superuser.com/