# Umbraco CMS in Azure unable to send email to new user

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I create a Umbraco CMS Web App in Azure. I login to the back-office of the Umbraco CMS and try to create new users on there. However, there is no email send to new users ether try create user or invite user.

It may related to SMTP settings in Umbraco, can I add it to the "Application Settings"of the Web App? Anyone try this before?

Comment: Are there any errors in the log files? Smtp settings for umbraco should be added to the web.config in `<system.net>`

Answer (score 1):

Add mail settings to your web.config like you would [other ASP.NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767450/how-does-my-asp-net-app-get-the-smtp-settings-automatically-from-web-config):

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="noreply@example.com">
        <network host="127.0.0.1" userName="username" password="password" />
    </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The [Umbraco Cloud documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Umbraco-Cloud/Set-Up/SMTP-settings/) also pertains to other hosting enviornments such as Azure Web Apps and gives some suggestions for SMTP services.

Comment: Thx, I fixed it now