# Yahoo Smtp mailsetting configuration

Tags: asp.net, smtp, yahoo

Does anyone know what the smtp mail configuration settings are that is needed in the web.config file to send outgoing mail through a form in ASP? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link: [Yahoo POP3 and SMTP Settings](http://techblissonline.com/yahoo-pop3-and-smtp-settings/)

My guess is the following should work in your code (not exactly sure about credentials as I do not have an account to test with):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();  
mail.From = new MailAddress("fromname@somewhere.com");  
mail.To.Add("toname@somewhereelse.com");  
mail.Subject = "The Subject";  
mail.Body = "Body text here";  
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;  
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;  
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");  
smtp.Port = 465;  // this could be 587, not sure
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("YourYahooId", "YourYahooPassword");  
smtp.EnableSsl = true;  // SSL is required I think
smtp.Send(mail);
```

The key is to make sure you are using SSL and send authentication credentials.  I don't think you will be able to do SSL with just the web.config mail settings.  Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454277/how-to-enable-ssl-for-smtpclient-in-web-config) for more information.

Comment: thanks, but now I recieve a SmtpException was unhandled by user code. I am not sure what this means.

Comment: The EnableSsl was throwing the same error, I tricked out my web.config file with the following.

   <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Jeff &lt;jeffrey.p***v@yahoo.Com&gt;">

        <network host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com" userName="********" password="******" />

Now I am up and running. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jpavlov If this helped you don't for get to give it an upvote or even mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Hi Kelsey,
It wasn't the enable SSL on my end, more of having the correct configuration settings on my part. See my comment above. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the [How to utilize Google gmail server in your.NET Web & Windows Applications](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=33) article. That code work for me. If it doesn't work for you, send mail to me(pandiansaamy@gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
SMTP_SERVER = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
SMTP_PORT = 587
SMTP_USERNAME = "username" // username@yahoo.com
SMTP_PASSWORD = "password"
```