# Password Recovery Control Timeout Connecting to Gmail

Tags: asp.net, web-config, timeout, gmail, password-recovery

I am using password recovery control and i am getting an error

The operation has timed out.

The web.config has the following code:

```
<system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="admin@mysite.com">
                <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="gmailPassword"
                    port="465" userName="username@gmail.com" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
</system.net>

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Clear"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

I have dropped the password recovery control, for automated e-mail, onto the page but it doesn't work.

What am i missing?

Tools used: asp.net 4 in VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible because Gmail requires SSL to be enabled for SMTP.

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can add set enableSsl="true". If you are using an older version of .NET, see [How to enable SSL for SmtpClient in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454277/how-to-enable-ssl-for-smtpclient-in-web-config).

Comment: now it shows: Your attempt to retrieve your password was not successful. Please try again

Comment: Actual Solution: http://forums.asp.net/t/1694020.aspx/1?ASP+net+password+recovery+control

Answer (score 2):

Gmail uses port 587, not 465.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="username@gmail.com" password="gmailPassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Still shows: Your attempt to retrieve your password was not successful. Please try again.