# Error while using Office365 SMTP in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, smtp, office365, smtp-auth

I am using Office365 web app SMTP to send email from Asp.Net but Its always throwing following error!

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse

The web.config is given below - with username & password changed

```
<network enableSsl="true"  host="pod51007.outlook.com" userName="XXXX" password="XXXXX" port="587" defaultCredentials="false" />
```

Comment: @Sandra Walters You should really convert this comment into an answer as it's how I solved my problem with the above error. I wish I could up-vote it as it deserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is misleading (as with most Microsoft errors!) - The error code looks very simular to a SMTP error and 5.7.1 is a relay error.  You may need to specify your development/production **public** IP address using the admin portal provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved so:

```
Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("your user", "your password")
client.Port = 587 
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com"
```

important are this instruction, without them is not working :

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
client.EnableSsl = True
```

Comment: This was very helpful! If you need to enable SSL in web.config, enableSsl="true" will work in .NET 4 - found this on http://stackoverflow.com/a/4973831/908677 and it worked for me.