# How to EnableSSL for Health Monitoring Notifications E-mail?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-3.5, smtpclient, health-monitoring

We are changing our email to Office 365, which force me to EnableSSL when I send Email from .NET. Since our Intranet Web Application run under .net 3.5, it look like I cannot [enable SSL for SmtpClient in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454277/how-to-enable-ssl-for-smtpclient-in-web-config). So I do something like this :

```
Dim Smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
Smtp.EnableSsl = Boolean.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SmtpEnableSsl"))
Smtp.Send(eMail)
```

But this ASP.net website is also configured to [Send E-mail for Health Monitoring Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227553%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I use the [SimpleMailWebEventProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99436a82%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do so, but it look like there is no option to EnableSsl on this provider.

What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21038/Using-SSL-with-System-Web-Management-MailWebEventP) that show how to force `EnableSsl` into a `MailWebEventProvider`.

I modified it so it use the `SimpleMailWebEventProvider` instead of the `TemplatedMailWebEventProvider` and use my `AppSettings` from the `web.config` to toggle the `EnableSsl` setting without changing the code, so the administrator will be able to switch it at will.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Management; 
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for SimpleMailWithSslWebEventProvider
/// </summary>
public class SimpleMailWithSslWebEventProvider : WebEventProvider 
{
    private SimpleMailWebEventProvider _SimpleProvider;
    public SimpleMailWithSslWebEventProvider() 
    {
        ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(SimpleMailWebEventProvider) 
            .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                            null, new Type[0], null);
        _SimpleProvider = (SimpleMailWebEventProvider)constructor 
            .Invoke(null); 
    } 
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config) 
    { 
        if (config == null) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("config"); 
        }
        _SimpleProvider.Initialize(name, config); 

        FieldInfo field = typeof(MailWebEventProvider) 
            .GetField("_smtpClient", 
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(_SimpleProvider, new SmtpClientWithSsl()); 
    } 


    public override void Flush() 
    {
        _SimpleProvider.Flush(); 
    } 
    public override void ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent raisedEvent) 
    {
        _SimpleProvider.ProcessEvent(raisedEvent); 
    } 
    public override void Shutdown() 
    {
        _SimpleProvider.Shutdown(); 
    } 
}
public class SmtpClientWithSsl : SmtpClient {
    public SmtpClientWithSsl() {
        base.EnableSsl = Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpEnableSsl"));
    }

}
```